# Animate UIView and keep corner radius as a circle

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I have a circle UIView :

```
  con=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-size-delta, y , size, size)];
    con.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
    con.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
    con.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
    con.layer.cornerRadius=con.frame.size.width/2.0;
    con.clipsToBounds=YES;
    [self addSubview:con];
```

Later i would like to change its size to a bigger one , but when i do that, at the start of the animation you see some rect shape , and than it changes back to circle.

I would like a flat animation where it keeps staying as a circle when its frame is being changing.

```
   CGRect frm=startConfrm; //original frame of the circle

    frm.size.width*=2;
    frm.size.height*=2;
     frm.origin.y=self.frame.size.height/2.0-frm.size.height/2.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         con.frame=frm;
                         con.layer.cornerRadius=con.frame.size.width/2.0;
                      }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){   }];
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to scale your view size, then you can use below code.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^{

con.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2, 2); // it will scale as double size

}completion:^(BOOL finished) {
 // do whatever at animation completion
      }
}];
```

To reset view back to normal size,

`con.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;`

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGAffineTransform/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGAffineTransformMakeScale

Comment: thanks it works great, but how can you bring it back to the previous size so next time i can animate it again( like beating heart)

Comment: actually i tried few different options, this animation is happens in intervals ,with timer, so every time it finished i would like to start over. so i tried to rescale it to 0,0 or 1,1  but what happens is that next time its size is much bigger, like the scaled one. i cant bring it to its original view, even if i set its frame back to 0.

Comment: It doesn't work for me: rounded corners become rect corners during the animation.

Answer (score 4):

To make a view "grow" into place, don't animate the frame. Animate the transform.

Load your subview from the nib. Set its transform to a scale of 0:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1);
```

Then add it to your superview.

Inside the animation block, set the transform to identity:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

And the view will grow to normal size. You may need to fiddle with the anchor point to make it grow from the right point.

You can also change the frame within the block, but to move a view only I prefer to change the center property, you shouldn't try to set the frame if you also have a transform.

Hope it helps you !!

> EDIT:
>   Replace your animation block code with the following code:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         CGAffineTransform newTransform;
                         newTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0, 0);
                         con.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(newTransform,2,2);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){   }];
```

Comment: thanks a lot, i am not sure whats the order of the operation. your first line say to set its transform to 1, which does nothing(?) than what the other line does? i dont get you, i am sorry..

Comment: If i do that ,nothing happens, the view disappears, and i get this error : <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix.